# How to allow multiple users to manage application running on server?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008

I'm not sure if the title makes sense.  Hard question to ask.

I have an application running on a server under my network account, and it's scheduled to run daily.

I can remote in with my user credentials and check on the application.

What if I want more than one person to be able to remote in and check it?  I can create a new account on the server, but it wouldn't have network rights and the application needs access to network folders.

What would be the best approach?

Thanks! :-)

P.S. Feel free to edit the tags.  I can't figure out what to pick.

Comment: Are you looking for a programing solution or configuration solution?  If configuration, then this belongs on serverfault.com. Either way, the question should be clearer.

Comment: Mary-Chan - I would recommend that you move your post over to serverfault.com as it is a site that is geared toward server administration.  StackOverflow is for programming related questions.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend your application writes out log files or status messages to a place the necessary users can see.  They can see the status via logs or output and don't need access to the scheduled task itself.

Answer (score 0):

well, in Unix you'd create a group and add users to said group.  I'm fairly certain you can do this on a windows server (make sure of course, that the group has permission to execute and read the app or the app's log files)